# Insert values in unique constraint with case sensitive in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique-constraint

I have to insert values with case sensitive in a table where it has unique constraint.
it looks like below example.

```sql
create table test1(
name1 varchar(100) unique)

insert into test1 select 'a'
insert into test1 select 'A'
```

I am getting error like below.

> (1 row affected)
> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 7
> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__test1__F0B6284CB05C7FE5'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.test1'. The duplicate key value is (A).

I am not tried but is expecting some solution.

[image]

Comment: You have to change the collation of your column so it doesn't ignore case on comparing. You probably have to drop the index first

Answer (score -1):

To successfully insert case-sensitive values into the table with a unique constraint, you need to make sure that the unique constraint is case insensitive. There are a couple of ways to achieve this:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (name1 varchar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS UNIQUE)

INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ('a')
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES ('A')
```

Comment: You probably meant `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` - where CS stands for _case sensitive_,